# How to get list of keyword found in a test script by using rflint library

Tags: python, robotframework, lint

I have to find count of "Click" keyword in particular test script in robot framework by using rflint library (Robotframework-lint). I have seen there was a custom class which gonna work suite level. Is there any class can get count keywords in test script level.

Comment: You mean how many `Click *` keywords are defined in your suite (file) or how many times such keywords are called in tests?

Comment: @JanKovařík - Yes its test script level, and not for suite level. I would like to get test1(testcase name) contains 3 clicks, test2(test case name) contains 2 clicks as output. Its more like test script level.

Comment: I would say rflint isn't the best tool to do such stat. SuiteVisitor seems to be more convenient for that. But maybe I'm wrong. I believe one of RF code contributors could provide more accurate info.

Comment: you just want the count of number of clicks in every single test case in a suite? not sure about the tools but there is a simple way to find it at run time, you can keep your custom click which will call the actual click! and using ${TEST NAME} you can keep track of count in every test case! Not sure if this helps! but its just a thought

Comment: Are you just wanting to print out a count, or throw an error if a click keyword has been used too many times, or print out the line number of each click keyword? Also, how do you define a "Click keyword"? One that begins with "click"?

Comment: Also, if a "click" keyword is called from some  other keyword (eg: "run keyword | click") do you want to count that?

Comment: @BryanOakley  Yep I need to increase the counter value as soon as it found matching string ("CLICK") value.